# How to cast DoubleType() to DecimalType(10,6) in spark for Parquet file generation?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, types, database-schema

I have data in JSON format:
`{"C_0_0": "INDIA", "C_0_1": 1219.765432, "C_0_2": {"C_1_0": "INDIA", "C_1_1": ["INDIA", "INDIA"]}}`

I want to save it to a parquet file. Upon saving it to a parquet file the interpreted datatype for column `C_0_1` is `DoubleType()` but I want to convert it to `DecimalType(10,6`
This is what I do for the following:

```py
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
hc = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
rdd = sc.parallelize([json_str])
nested_df = hc.read.json(rdd)
nested_df.show(20,False)
print("Original Pyspark Schema: ", nested_df.schema)
new_pyspark_schema = StructType([
                                  StructField('C_0_0', StringType(), True), 
                                  StructField('C_0_1', DecimalType(10,6), True), 
                                  StructField('C_0_2', StructType([
                                                                      StructField('C_1_0', StringType(), True), 
                                                                      StructField('C_1_1', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)
                                                                  ]), True
                                              )
                                  ])
new_rdd = sc.parallelize([json_str])
new_df = hc.read.schema(new_pyspark_schema).json(new_rdd)
new_df.repartition(1).write.option("schema", new_pyspark_schema).parquet(file_location)
parDf = sqlContext.read.parquet(file_location)
parDf.show(20,False)
parDf.printSchema()
```

But the parquet file generated cannot interpret the column `C_0_1`?
Error message: `pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Cannot extract statistics for type`

What might be the issue?

Comment: Hi. what's your spark version?

Comment: Spark version is 3.3.2

Comment: Why do you use a `HiveContext`? It is deprecated since spark 2.0.

Comment: And `SQLContext` is deprecated since 3.0

Comment: I am using HiveContext for reading json.

Comment: How to read the json then?

Comment: Apart from that, strangely, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Does pyspark.read.json(rdd) work

Comment: Use the spark session `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html and then `spark.read.json`

Comment: @Oli any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, I was not able to reproduce your problem. However, it could be related to the fact that you use `HiveContext`, deprecated since 2.0.0 and `SQLContext` deprecated since 3.0.0. In spark 3.x, here is a more modern way to do what you want:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

rdd = sc.parallelize([json_str])
# You can use your schema as is
new_df = spark.read.schema(new_pyspark_schema).json(rdd)
new_df.write.parquet(parquet_location)
spark.read.parquet(parquet_location).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- C_0_0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_1: decimal(10,6) (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C_1_0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C_1_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```